# How do I get a list values and columns using python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, dataframe

Apologies for the noobish question but....

I have a dataframe (in python using pandas, with headers) which looks like this:

```
   Pink     Blue    Yellow   Green  
 --------- ------- -------- ------- 
  Jackson   Bryan   Bruce    Benji  
  James     Jonah   Jenny    Kevin  
  Tyson     Jenna   Mike     none   
  Kendall   Amy     Alison   none   
  Ben       none    none     none
```

How do I get a list of teams and names to look like below?

```
  Pink    Jackson  
  Pink    James    
  Blue    Bryan    
  ...              
  Green   Kevin
```

Comment: So you want all pairs of column name + value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you want to have all pairs of column name + value. [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) can do that for you:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({"Pink": ["Jackson", "James"], "Blue": ["Bryan", None]})
 pd.melt(df)
```

Result:

```
  variable    value
0     Pink  Jackson
1     Pink    James
2     Blue    Bryan
3     Blue     None
```

And if you only want a 2-dimensional numpy array you can do:

```
pd.melt(df).values
```

Result:

```
array([['Pink', 'Jackson'],
       ['Pink', 'James'],
       ['Blue', 'Bryan'],
       ['Blue', None]], dtype=object)
```

And as matman9 pointed out just add a `.tolist()` after the `.values` to get a python list.

Comment: Beat me to it :D

Comment: to get the list you can add .tolist() after values

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the earlier answer I'd suggest filtering out the `None`'s:

```
for t in filter(lambda x: x[1], pd.melt(df).values.tolist()):
    print('{:8} {}'.format(*t))
```